# Why isn't my dequeue method working for my treeMap PriceQueue?

Tags: java, data-structures, queue, nodes, treemap

I have a PriceQueue class and I have gotten all my tests to pass except 2. Thenones that fail are:

```
public void test05DeleteBackInOrder() {
    PriceQueue pq = new PriceQueue();
    pq.enqueue(p101);
    pq.enqueue(p202);
    pq.enqueue(p303);
    pq.enqueue(p404);
    pq.enqueue(p505);
    assertTrue(pq.delete(p303));
    assertTrue(pq.delete(p404));
    assertTrue(pq.delete(p505));
    assertEquals(p101, pq.dequeue());
    assertEquals(p202, pq.dequeue());

    pq = new PriceQueue();
    pq.enqueue(p101);
    pq.enqueue(p202);
    pq.enqueue(p303);
    pq.enqueue(p404);
    pq.enqueue(p505);
    assertTrue(pq.delete(p303));
    assertTrue(pq.delete(p404));
    assertTrue(pq.delete(p505));
    pq.enqueue(p303);
    pq.enqueue(p404);
    assertEquals(p101, pq.dequeue());
    assertEquals(p202, pq.dequeue());
    assertEquals(p303, pq.dequeue()); //This is where it is failing
    assertEquals(p404, pq.dequeue());
}
```

and

```
public void test05DeleteMiddleInOrder() {
    PriceQueue pq = new PriceQueue();
    pq.enqueue(p101);
    pq.enqueue(p202);
    pq.enqueue(p303);
    pq.enqueue(p404);
    pq.enqueue(p505);
    assertTrue(pq.delete(p202));
    assertTrue(pq.delete(p303));
    assertTrue(pq.delete(p404));
    assertEquals(p101, pq.dequeue());
    assertEquals(p505, pq.dequeue()); // This is where it fails

    pq = new PriceQueue();
    pq.enqueue(p101);
    pq.enqueue(p202);
    pq.enqueue(p303);
    pq.enqueue(p404);
    pq.enqueue(p505);
    assertTrue(pq.delete(p202));
    assertTrue(pq.delete(p303));
    assertTrue(pq.delete(p404));
    pq.enqueue(p202);
    pq.enqueue(p303);
    assertEquals(p101, pq.dequeue());
    assertEquals(p505, pq.dequeue());
    assertEquals(p202, pq.dequeue());
    assertEquals(p303, pq.dequeue());
}
```

These are the ones that are failing and I don't understand where it is that I am missing deleting the prie so that it dequeues correctly.
Here is my code here:

```
public Price dequeue() {
    if (isEmpty()) throw new NoSuchElementException("Queue underflow");
    Price price = first.price;
    first = first.next;
    n--;
    if (isEmpty()) last = null; 
    hold.remove(hold.lastKey());
    // to avoid loitering
    return price;
}


/**
 * Deletes a Price from the queue if it was present.
 * @param price the Price to be deleted.
 * @return {@code true} if the Price was deleted and {@code false} otherwise
 */
public boolean delete(Price price) {
    // TODO implelment me!!!
    // Make sure the running time is no worse than logrithmic!!!
    // You will want to use Java's TreeMap class to map Prices to the node
    // that precedes the Price in the queue
    //last node==special case
    //^^ requires resetting prev. to null, and val to next
    if (hold.containsKey(price)) {
        Node temp = hold.get(price);
        //if (price.equals(f))
        if (price.equals(first.price) && n >= 3) {
            first = first.next;
            n--;
            hold.remove(price);
            return true;
        }
        if (price.equals(first.price)) {
            first = first.next;
            hold.remove(price);
            n--;
            return true;
        }
        if (price.equals(last.price)) {
            temp.next = null;
            last = temp;
            n--;
            hold.remove(price);
            return true;
        }
        if (temp.next != (null)) {
            temp.next = temp.next.next;
            n--;
            hold.remove(price);
            return true;
        }

        return true;
    }
    else return false;

}
```

Any help is appreciated even if it is a tip or hint. If anything else is needed please let me know and I will supply, these are just the parts of my code.
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

A quick answer about standard de-queuing would be to simply return the output of remove.

```
public Price dequeue(){
    return some_list.remove(0); //null if empty
}
```

Remove returns the element it removes, and automatically shifts the elements following the removed item 1 to the left. If the item does not exist (list is empty) then it will return null.

Comment: PS: there is also a standard queue object in java.

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply! This won't work, as it is a queue mapped with a TreeMap class.

Comment: @A.Garcia Ah, sorry for the misunderstanding. Since a TreeMap is automatically sorted, isn't it possible to do tMap.remove(tMap.firstKey()).